# Python Upgrade with Airflow Celery Scheduler

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, python-3.8

I am upgrading from Python3.7 to Python3.8 and using airflow 1.10.15. I did this on a linux box by installing 3.8 from source alongside 3.7 as to not disturb any ongoing processes and using update-alternatives to select 3.8 as the current version. I have re-installed all relevant packages and dependencies. However, after re-initializing the airflow db with `airflow initdb` and `airflow db upgrade`, I am running into an issue:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py", line 1723, in process
    return loads(value)
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5
```

It also appears to be using the site-packages from the 3.7 installation.

This box has the webserver, scheduler, and worker that runs other queues on other boxes as well. I have restarted all service files associated with this and was hoping someone may have an idea of what I am doing incorrectly. Thanks.